# SmartSync In Native Android Application

Tags: smartsync

Im trying to Implement Offline Synchronization by using SmartSync.The libraries have already been Referenced , and Im getting access to SmartStoreSDKManager. But inside the SmartSync Package im only having the manifest file , there is no SmartSync Manager inside it. Ive read the Documentation , its said to add libs/SmartSync in the Module Dependency, done that and no change.Anyone guide me what am i doing wrong ?Im not able to access the smartsync methods since they are not available. Ps: Im new to Salesforce Platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK solved it, You need to install node.js and create forcedroid . and it will generate the necessary files inside the smartsync and salesforce SDK. and we can copy the files we want and replace in the existing Project folders.